# What is the best way to define a double constant in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants

What is the best way to define a double constant in a namespace? For example

```
// constant.h
namespace constant {
    static const double PI = 3.1415926535;
}

// No need in constant.cpp
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: Maybe you should clarify "best" and show some other options.

Comment: You don't need the static.  Anything that is `const` is implicitly static.

Comment: And you've done it exactly the way I would.  No need for any added new features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say:

-- In c++14:

```
namespace constant 
{
  template <typename T = double>
  constexpr T PI = T(3.1415926535897932385);
}
```

-- In c++11:

```
namespace constant 
{
  constexpr double PI = 3.1415926535897932385;
}
```

-- In c++03 :

```
namespace constant 
{
  static const double PI = 3.1415926535897932385;
}
```

---

Note that if your constant does not have a trivial type and you are within a shared library, i would advise to avoid giving it internal linkage at global/namespace scope, i don't know the theory about this but in practice it does tend to randomly mess things up :)

Comment: What is the consequence of the C++14 example compared to the C++11 one? The former looks overkill to me...

Comment: @FabioA.Correa you can chose the type of `PI`, you won't need casts for operations using something else than double, and i don't see any overhead except one more small line of code. `PI`is the very example used in the paper introducing variable templates, for further problems it solves the best source is still that paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf

Comment: In C++03, does the assignment need to be in a separate source file?  What happens if it is assigned in the header file?

Comment: @Drax, I wasn't talking about overhead because evidently both examples are compile-time. I found your comment very educative, thanks.

Comment: Your last suggestion doesn't work.  `static const double PI;` shouldn't even compile.  The usual solution would be to just write `double const PI = 3.14;` in a header.  (If the object is const, it's implicitly static.)

Comment: All of your suggestions have internal linkage.  There's no real advantage of using anything other than `double const PI = 3.;`, other than added verbosity.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In C++03, the assignment cannot be in a separate file, despite what he has written.  `PI` has internal linkage, and must be initialized when it is defined.