# What is the correct way to initialize static data members in C++ (98, 11 and 14)

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members, c++14, c++98

What is the right way to initialize `static` data members in C++? I'm also interested in how it has changed from C++98, to C++11 to C++14.

Here is an example:

```
// bufferedOutput.h
class BufferedOutput
{
 // Static member declaration.
 static long bytecount;
};

// bufferedOutput.cpp
long BufferedOutput::bytecount = 50;
```

Are there other ways to initialize `static` data members?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26429556/1147772

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The rules have always been as follows:

- A `const` static data member (SDM) of integral or enumeration type can be initialised in class with a constant expression.
- A `constexpr` SDM must be initialised in class with a constant expression.

  C++17 no longer requires an initializer when the default constructor initialises every member. Also, `constexpr` SDMs are implicitly inline variables, which makes their declaration a definition (external definitions are now deprecated).
- Other kinds of SDMs can have an initializer at their definition (which is in class if that SDM is declared `inline`).

Nothing has substantially changed between C++03 and C++11+ for code that is valid in both languages.

Note that for SDMs that are not inline, the in-class declaration is not a definition—regardless of whether an initializer is provided—and they must be defined if they are odr-used.

As of C++17, we can make your SDM inline, which makes its in-class declaration a definition:

```
class BufferedOutput
{
  static inline long bytecount = 50;
};
```

Comment: You should mention that an out-of-class definition may still be needed even when you can use an in-class initializer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I thought thats obvious since the thing in class is always only a declaration (and a definition is needed if the entity is odr-used).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not obvious to lots of people who think that the in-class initializer also provides a definition :-\ Anyway, if allowed to I would give you another +1 now for the final note!

Comment: to be MISRA compliant the initialiser should be `50L` otherwise you're assigning an integer to long.

Comment: @Anonymouse `long` is guaranteed to be able to represent any value that `int` can represent.

Comment: @Columbo That may bet true, but my point still stands... "MISRA C++2008 5-0-8 - An explicit integral or floating-point conversion shall not increase the size of the underlying type of a cvalue expression."

Comment: @Anonymouse Appears as if they're talking about explicit conversions. And cvalues (complex values). Which this code has neither of.