# initialize static pointer array c++

Tags: c++

I have my class:

```
class Exec {
  static Process* procs_table[];

 public:
 Exec(int num, info_init_proc* proc);
};
```

info_init_proc is a custom struct with information necessary for initializing the Process object

And try to create the constructor as below:

```
Exec::Exec(int num, info_init_proc* proc) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     Exec::procs_table[i] = new Process(proc[i]);
  }
}
```

It can be compiled, but when i build i get the "Undefined symbol procs_table" error.

What should be modified ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a static member in a constructor.  A constructor is creating an instance of the class, yet the static member is shared by all instances.

Here's a great post on static [initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26648817/7560372)

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem is that your static array is declared, but not defined. Adding this line to your CPP file will fix that:

```
Process* Exec::procs_table[SOME_MAX_VALUE];
```

However, it appears that the choice of `static` is fundamentally incorrect here, because you do not know `n`, the size of the allocation, until run-time. In this situation a singleton object with `std::vector` of process pointers would be more appropriate.